# How can compartment bay loading informating be derived from the IATA load message (LDM)?

Tags: airport, ground-operations

In the IATA [Airport Handling Manual procedures](https://www.iata.org/publications/Pages/airport-handling-manual.aspx), messages are send to communicate with the transit station to describe the cargo load. The [Load message LDM](http://wiki.aviabit.ru/images/4/49/AHM583.pdf) (AHM 583) is sent primarily to enable the transit station to know in advance the load which continues on the same aircraft.

> LDM ZZ999/13.ZZOEA.Y136.2/4
>   -SHJ.15/22/3/1.T1500.3/1000.4/500.PAX/40.PAD/0
>   -CMB.27/22/12/3.T3500.1/2800.5/700.PAX/61.PAD/0 SI

In here we got  hold id 3 total gross weight 1000kg,...
In our automated system, we need info in compartment bay level.

How can we get those information?

- Any other message like Container / Pallet Distribution Message CPM (AHM 587)?
- Or we have to manage manually (should distribute by load controller)

Comment: It's related to [IATA Telex](https://javadude.wordpress.com/2012/04/08/online-iata-telex-processor/), but the question is definitely unclear.

Comment: thanks @mins yep It is related with IATA telex.. I parsed those LDM message. but those details are in abstract level (e.g total gross weight 1000kg in hold id 3 --> refer 3/1000). how can we get some specific details like what is the weight distribute in compartment bay (32L). note several compartment make a hold level. can any one who handling AHM messaging / Sita telex plz help me

Comment: I'll edit your post to make it more readable for this community. If you want to roll back to your version and improve it on your own, just use the [`edit`](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/25125/edit) link. You should still explain the context: Are you a developer or a user? Are you using an application or an API? Which one?

Answer (score 1):

Paranee,
There is no such detail in the LDM, it is just a WEIGHT value. There maybe specifics for certain SL/DG (review AHM again for those) as some SL/DG are required to show location and some location and weight - explained in AHM.

BUT - LDM is just an overview, not very specific as it does not need to be. For a through flight A>B>C, where A is OFFLINE to your system, if you have received teletype LDM for processing and you are doing the sector B>C then any load B>C is just shown (know by the system) as TRA (transit) load - nothing more. No more detail.

However for unitized aircraft, the CPM complements the LDM to show the detail required by bay as opposed to HOLD and/or COMPARTMENT.